# RelayCommand Throws InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

Using the current version (version 5.2.0) of MVVM Light, I am encountering an exception from calling [Convert.ChangeType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130977(v=vs.110).aspx) internal to MVVM Light RelayCommandGeneric when using a `Nullable<int>` (or `int?`) as the parameter.

**The Question**
How can I use a `Nullable<int>` as the command parameter for the `RelayCommand` when sometimes the binding binds to a null value and sometimes to an integer?  I am not seeing an issue when binding to a non-nullable integer.

**Background**
I found a similar story in the issues tracker on CodePlex ([issue 7588](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7588)) which says it was resolved in 2012.  Also of note is that there is a [pull request](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/marc80/MvvmLightRelayCommandFix/contribution/3327) that attempts to address that issue - however it appears that the request was not merged.

Comment: Two down votes and zero comments, not a good start to this question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a real answer, but a workaround for this issue is to instead of using a `Nullable<int>` is to just use an `int` as the generic parameter type and in the XAML binding provide a `TargetNullValue` of a sentinel value.  Then in the execute action / can execute action check for the sentinel value.

In the XAML:

```
<Button Command="MyCommand" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding PathToNullableInt, TargetNullValue=0}" 
        Content="Do Something"/>
```

Then in the view model:

```
public RelayCommand<int> MyCommand = new RelayCommand<int>((i) =>
{
    if (i != 0)
    {
        DoSomething(i);
    }
});
```